# Why when i am closing a JFrame window that was launched from an Eclipse plugin the whole Eclipse framework stops also?

Tags: eclipse-plugin

I have created an Eclipse plugin that adds a button at the menu bar and when you click the button a new Java GUI applications is starting(the application was implemented with the support of awt and swing library frameworks).
My problem is that when i am closing the Java GUI application(click the "X" icon at up-right) then the Eclipse framework also stops and the process is stopped.
That's the code below where i call the Java GUI application to start from my menuhandler:

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
  public void run() {
   new atag.gui.MainFrame().setVisible(true);
  }
 });
```

I coded the GUI with Netbeans Frames tool.

Do you have any recommendations or how i can fix that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Your plugin probably calls `System.exit` somewhere.

Comment: What i actually did and it worked was : this.setDefaultCloseOperation(HIDE_ON_CLOSE) inside my frame